# Django - How to display two texts of equal length line by line?

Tags: python

For example:

```
text_1 = "asd 13 awgg aeg wef 234 adfgg asdtt ..."
text_2 = "ASD 13 AWGG AEG WEF 234 ADFGG ASDTT ..."
```

desired_output_1 = Both texts are displayed line by line (one line of text_1 on top of another line of text_2, and such. Not side-by-side) in a div.

```
desired_output_2 = "asd ASD 13 13 awgg AWGG aeg AEG wef WEF 234 234 adfgg ADFGG asdtt ASDTT ..."
```

For illustration's sake, I use upper and lower case here, but the actually texts cannot be so easily converted.

Both texts are very long and have words separated by spaces.

Each text is stored in a field of the same model.

How can I achieve this in the final html output?

Now I just need to loop over the two strings and interpolate the words one by one as described above in 'desired_output_2'. How can I achieve that in Python?

Comment: share your code snippet, what you have tried so far @ZilongL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the python code that works, you can modify in this by your considerations

```
a='aaaaa bbbbbb cccccc '
b='AAAAA BBBBBB CCCCCC '
d=''
for i in a:
    d= d + i
    if i == ' ':
        for i in b:
            d= d+i
            if i == ' ':
            f=b.split()
            f.pop(0)
            b=' '.join(f)   
            break
```

Output:
`aaaaa AAAAA bbbbbb BBBBBB cccccc CCCCCC`

Comment: @ZilongL let me know if it helps

Comment: Great solution! Thank you.